# Meta is null when trying to parse json String to JsonApiModel

Tags: android, kotlin, json-api

I am following JsonAPI schema and using the [kotlin-jsonapix](https://github.com/infinum/kotlin-jsonapix) library.
When trying to convert from json, I am always getting null `meta`.

This is my json:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "st",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "end_date": "2222-12-31",
      "payment_id": "1",
      "start_date": "2020-12-13",
      "status": "ACTIVE"
    },
    "meta": {
      "detail": "user details"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my model:

```
@Serializable
@JsonApiX(type = "st")
data class StModel(
    @SerialName("end_date") val subscriptionEndDate: String? = null,
    @SerialName("start_date") val subscriptionStartDate: String? = null,
    @SerialName("status") val subscriptionStatus: String? = null,
    @SerialName("payment_id") val paymentId: String? = null,
) : JsonApiModel()

@Serializable
@JsonApiXMeta(type = "st")
data class StMeta(val detail: String) : Meta
```

and I am using below statement to get StModel from jsonString:

```
TypeAdapter_StModel().convertFromString(jsonString)
```

and I get null `meta`.

Can someone please explain if I am doing anything wrong or is it an issue with the library itself.